# Custom editor in angular ui-grid

Tags: angularjs-directive, angular-ui-grid

I'm trying to write own cell editor for ui-grid. There are 10 colors: 0=black, 1=white, 2=gray, and so on. I'm showing the numerical value in the cell as small colored div. On editing I would like to have a div with ten small colored divs which changes the ngModel value on click.

There are two problems I have:

1. How get I the value of selected color back to ui-grid?
2. How get I blur event on div containing colored divs?

Example:

[image]

Can someone give me a hint?

Here are my files:

gridController.js:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    ...
    editableCellTemplate: `template/cellEdit${c.cellType}`
}
```

cellEditColor.jade:

```
form(name="inputForm")
    edit-color(style="position:absolute;",ng-class="'colt' + col.uid",ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD")
```

editColor.jade

```
div(style="tabindex=-1;background-color:#def;")
    .colorView(ng-click="selectColor(c.id)",ng-repeat="c in colors",style="background-color:{{c.v}}",ng-class="{'selected': c.id == selected }")
```

editColor.js

```
sim.directive('editColor', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
            scope.selected = scope.ngModel;

            scope.colors = [
                { id: 0, v: '#000' },
                { id: 1, v: '#fff' },
                { id: 2, v: '#aaa' },
                { id: 3, v: '#840' },
                { id: 4, v: '#fc8' },
                { id: 5, v: '#f00' },
                { id: 6, v: '#ff0' },
                { id: 7, v: '#0f0' },
                { id: 8, v: '#00f' },
                { id: 9, v: '#f0f' }
            ];

            scope.$on('uiGridEventStartCellEdit', function () {
                elem.focus();
            });

            elem.bind('blur', function () {
                // this never occurs
                scope.$emit('uiGridEventEndCellEdit');
            });

            elem.bind('mousedown', function (evt) {
                evt.stopPropagation();
            });

            scope.selectColor = function (c) {
                // update grid with c
                scope.$emit('uiGridEventEndCellEdit');
            }

        },
        templateUrl: 'sim/template/editColor'
    };
}]);
```